# "My mother is always asking after you." Is it a correct sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

*My mother is always asking after you.*

Is it a correct sentence to use? Can someone explain it please.

Comment: I recommend you give us a bit more information, otherwise your post is likely to be closed. Is your question about the verb _to ask after_? Or are you unsure about the use of the present continuous in combination with the adverb _always_? The sentence is grammatical, but whether or not it  is 'correct' depends on the context in which you wish to use it.

Comment: @Shoe why not try to "save" the question. The phrasal verb is, after all, rather uncommon. It seems the OP has left the website, and I don't hold much hope that they will return.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I'm not sure if the question is about the phrasal verb. It could be that the OP has learned that the present simple is used with frequency adverbs such as _always_ and is surprised to see the present continuous here. My comment above was an attempt to save the question by asking for elucidation. I'm not sure how else it can be saved.

Comment: @Shoe  What would be "wrong" with editing the question and asking about the two things together? If the OP has left the tavern but new customers keep turning up, what are they going to do? They're going to find a new tavern, e.g. Yahoo! or Quora.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I'm in full accord with your sympathetic approach to newbie posts, but I don't see how the question can be rescued. It is either  closeable as request for proof-reading or for failing to include research. Without knowing what meaning the OP wishes to convey (i.e. the context), it is guesswork. Maybe the OP will return and confirm that the question is about the phrasal verb, in which case you have provided a good answer. However, it may still be closed for the reasons above.

Comment: @Shoe oh, I see. You had already cast your vote to close it.

Answer (score 1):

*[To ask after](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ask-after?s=t)* or *to inquire after* someone is a slightly more formal way of asking about the health or well-being of someone, especially, as in this case, in reporting the speech of others. The mother probably asks periodically, “How is [personal name] doing?” or something more specific about a particular condition: “Has [personal name] recovered from his/her surgery?"

Comment: The downvote is an attempt to avoid site mediocrity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: When concision is mediocrity, then we're all in trouble. I included a dictionary reference, explained the usual social context for the expression, and commented on register. I assumed the OP is not interested in an exhaustive discussion of the expression or, say, alternates in Scotland.

Comment: No; answering questions totally lacking reasonable research and not specifying a particular query. But you're also supposed to attribute references correctly; this is to conform with copyright, not just ELU, laws.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: So you want "dictionary.com defines..." rather than a simple link to the entry there? I would imagine the link itself is reference enough, since, you know, this is the internet.

Comment: Why don't you look at what ELU policy is on correct attribution, rather than argue?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing suggests since I am not citing verbatim but merely linking to a common reference source that no written attribution, such as "According to dictionary.com," would be necessary. But that's not the real issue, is it?

Answer (score 0):

> My mother is always asking after you.

The OP's sentence is perfectly correct. The verb that comes after the adverb *always* often takes the gerund form.

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ask), **to ask after + direct object**, or if you are a Scot, **to ask for** is a Britishism.

> **1.2** "ask after" or Scottish "ask for" British [no object]
>   Enquire about the health or well-being of.
>
> *‘if I see him I'll tell him you were asking after him’*
>   *‘He asked after my parents and enquired into the wellbeing of my wife and kids.’*

I feel it has become rather dated nowadays, and people will normally ***ask about*** a person's health or well-being.
<sub>P.S I don't really understand why OD says “[no object]” maybe someone  can clarify that for me.</sub>

To verify whether the British phrasal verb is becoming outdated, I checked the British corpus using the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%20asked%20after%2Che%20asked%20after%2Cto%20ask%20after&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20asked%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20asked%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20ask%20after%3B%2Cc0) tool.

[image]

Not all the instances listed are polite inquiries about people's well being, but many are. Here are some examples of usage:

1795 • *till about this time next year, when I will call [to ask after his health](https://books.google.it/books?id=3cUBAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA198&dq=%22to%20ask%20after%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs__TWiLzZAhURwlkKHQ1pAnoQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22to%20ask%20after%22&f=false), which, I hope, will long ere that be established;*

1954 • *[He asked after my girl](https://books.google.it/books?id=sH0WCtUIXDIC&pg=PA8&dq=%22he%20asked%20after%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlqpn7ibzZAhXIzlkKHSCPBDkQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22he%20asked%20after%22&f=false), we talked about pleasant things, and then he called his batman to make coffee for us.*

1952-1961 • *She asked after you but I didn't know then where you were.' '[She asked after me?](https://books.google.it/books?id=dnZbAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Well,+to+tell+you+the+truth+she+asked+after+all+her+old+boy+friends%22&dq=%22Well,+to+tell+you+the+truth+she+asked+after+all+her+old+boy+friends%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin0-60jLzZAhXPqFkKHcmOBSEQ6AEILTAB)' 'Well, to tell you the truth she asked after all her old boy friends - but you especially. Go and see her if you've got time.*

Merriam-Webster, an American dictionary, omits this definition from its database and limits itself to citing two idiomatic meanings of ***[ask for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ask)***

> **1.** — **ask for it**
>   informal
>   : to behave in a way that invites punishment or retribution
>   • *Experts used to think that battered women were "asking for it"—somehow masochistically provoking abuse from their men. Mercifully, that idea has now been discredited.*
>
> **2.** — **ask for trouble**
>   informal
>   : to behave in a way that is likely to result in trouble
>   • *… you are asking for trouble if you try to lift too much weight …*

Short list of texts cited:

1. *Gleanings Through Wales, Holland and Westphalia*, by Mr. Pratt 2. *The Sergeant in the Snow* by Mario Rigoni Stern 3. *Sword of Honour* by Evelyn Waugh

Comment: I've never heard anyone saying "ask after" in that context. Always "ask for". Whatever about what's grammatically correct, it's not used in normal conversations.

Comment: @Andre better take it up with the editor of Oxford Living Dictionaries and Evelyn Waugh, etc.

Comment: I'm alright, cheers. Just mentioning it because it's not a phrase I'd teach someone learning English.

Comment: @Andre - If you "as for" someone you're asking for them to be brought to you, or to be connected to them on the telephone, or whatever.  "Ask after" means to ask *about*.  It's a bit archaic, but has certainly been seen in American novels of the 20th Century.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not debating the fact the meaning of "ask after". I'm just pointing out that in normal conversation in 2018, we use "ask for" for both cases. Depending on the context, it means whichever one is suitable.

Comment: @Andre - In my experience, "ask for" is not used in the same sense as "ask after" in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks Fair enough. I've never heard anyone say it in my life though.